# React - Module Build Failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to a basic React setup with Webpack, but currently getting this console error on the html I'm trying to render.

Not sure why, any ideas?

Module build failed: SyntaxError:

Javascript

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <p>h</p>
        )
    }
}

render(<App/>, document.getElementById('main'));
```

Webpack Config

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || "production";

module.exports = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: {
        filename: "./index.js"
    },
    output: {
        filename: "build/bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015-native-modules']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: { warnings: false },
            output: { comments: false },
            sourcemap: true
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': { NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(nodeEnv
            )}
        })
    ]
}
```

Package.JSON

```
{
  "name": "joe-react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --progress --watch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015-native-modules": "^6.9.4",
    "webpack": "^2.3.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need babel react preset, and I see you use strange preset now, use es2015 instead

Comment: Thanks for this. For anyone wondering I uninstalled 'babel-preset-es2015-native-modules' and installed 'babel-preset-es2015' instead and changed my webpack.config.js to 'es2015' instead of 'es2015-native-modules'.

I also installed 'babel-preset-react' and added that in my presets in webpack.config.js.